# The difference between using tcpdump and rawsocket to sniff packets?

Tags: android, tcpdump, raw-sockets

I tried to capture the package on VoLTE android phone.
Which has an IPv6 addr when I turn on the [VoLTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_LTE).

[connect to android phone shell through adb shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csUrx.png)

This address is used by the phone to connect to the ims core net.

What I trying to do :

sniff the package on this interface by tcpdump. But I can't get anything.
Is there any one do the similar thing?

```
  # tcpdump -i rmnet_ims -s 0 -n -w package.pcap
```

next step I try to use rawsocket to sniff the packet .
I don't know the difference between them.
What I know is that tcpdump base on libpcap .
And if the package doesn't go into the linux network stack, tcpdump 
can not catch them.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have root access to the phone, you should get all the packets sent/received by the phone on that interface. The only concern is, they would be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have root access, and I can use qxdm to get the SIP signal message, but I can not get SIP signal message through tcpdump. [Dissecting VoLTE
Exploiting Free Data Channels and Security Problems](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7502-dissecting_volte)

Comment: And I found that the SIP signal message is now handled by CP(maybe baseband). And they said to  do Reverse Engineering to baseband to catch the SIP signal message, but I have no experience in this area. Cloud you give some advice, thanks a lot!